# X-Error from backend

Tags: android, okhttp

I want to parse error. 
After send request to the backend I get response:

```
11-24 14:23:35.553 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 24 Nov 2017 13:23:35 GMT
11-24 14:23:35.554 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: Server: Apache
11-24 14:23:35.554 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
11-24 14:23:35.555 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: X-Runtime: 0.010097
11-24 14:23:35.555 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
11-24 14:23:35.556 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
11-24 14:23:35.556 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
11-24 14:23:35.557 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: X-Error: This day is not in the range of tracking days
11-24 14:23:35.557 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: X-Request-Id: dab1d774-257e-4f05-8ceb-48c61b8a0254
11-24 14:23:35.557 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.1.11
11-24 14:23:35.558 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: Status: 404 Not Found
11-24 14:23:35.558 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 0
11-24 14:23:35.559 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
11-24 14:23:35.559 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
11-24 14:23:35.560 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
11-24 14:23:35.564 22759-26071/eu.incare.android D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (0-byte body)
```

and this is my error parser:

```
 public void parseNetworkError(Throwable t) {

        if (t instanceof UnknownHostException) {
            getView().showError(R.string.error_message_no_wifi);
            return;
        }

        if (t instanceof SocketTimeoutException || t instanceof SocketException) {
            getView().showError(R.string.error_message_timeout);
            return;
        }

        if (t instanceof IOException) {
            getView().showError(R.string.error_message_connection_error);
            return;
        }

        if (t instanceof HttpException) {
            HttpException httpException = (HttpException) t;
            try {
                String jsonError = httpException.response().errorBody().source().readUtf8();
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .registerTypeAdapter(ApiException.class, new ApiExceptionTypeAdapter())
                        .create();
                ApiException apiException = gson.fromJson(jsonError, ApiException.class);

                if (apiException == null) {
                    apiException = new ApiException();
                }

                if (apiException.getErrorMessage() == 0) {
                    if (httpException.code() == 500) {
                        getView().showError(R.string.error_message_server_error);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        getView().showError(R.string.error_message_unexpected_api_error);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                getView().showError(apiException.getErrorMessage());
            } catch (IOException | JsonSyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                getView().showError(R.string.error_message_unexpected_api_error);
            } catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                getView().showError(R.string.error_message_unknown);
            }
        } else {
            getView().showError(R.string.error_message_unknown);
        }
    }
```

but in Throwable I can't see X-Error message. How can I get this? I use OkHttp and retrofit.

Comment: `httpException.response().headers()` should have your headers.

Comment: @CommonsWare thx, works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OkHttp `Response` has a `headers()` method that allows you to access the response headers. Your `httpException` has `response()` which returns the `Response`, and so you should be able to get to your `X-Error` header there.